# Django logging with user/ip

Tags: django, logging

I am using the "logging" module to log a very large amount of messages. I would like to add "user" (request.user) to the log. But while it is available in the view function, I don't want to pass it to all helpers.

Does anyone know a way to this ?
[I was thinking of maybe somehow walking the trace until I find a function with "request" in its args]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hacky way to do this is to stick the request (or request.user) in [threadlocal storage](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookThreadlocalsAndUser).

The correct and maintainable way is to explicitly pass the data you need into the functions that need it. If doing this seems too onerous, it may reveal a deeper problem in how you've structured your code.

Comment: Since this is only a debugging tool, I don't want to start passing around the 'context' between all functions. Looks like a perfect way to insert hooks into a dev server. Thanks !